# How to disable Activity 1 after going to Activity 2?

Tags: java, android

I'm doing an app in Android. The problem is that when I open a new activity (via the OnClick button) the device's memory is charged with the previous one (Activity1).
Does anyone know how can I turn off Activity 1 (e.g. using the OnDestroy method or otherwise) ???

Comment: You can use the `onStop` of the **Activity**

Answer (score 2):

Simple You need to pass flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP with Intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do never call yourself the Activity livecycle callbacks like `OnDestroy()` `OnStop()` etc.
Before calling your new Activity, just call `finish()`

Answer (score 0):

Calling `finish()` inside `onStop()` will do the work.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // call the superclass method first
    super.onStop();

    finish(); // will close the activity completely. 
}
```

Or alternatively do as below:

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```